# Preserve datalist data on load event in c#

Tags: c#

I have datalist containing radio buttons and check boxes. If I select some of them and then redirect to another aspx page. when I come to previous page the radio buttons and check boxes in datalist must be selected. I have selected data in session variable. How to do this using c#.

Comment: <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4"/>
<ItemTemplate>
<table>       %#Eval("data")%>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

Comment: And I am saving html in data variable like -
data += "<tr><td width='2%' > <input name='"+ inputName +"' type='"+ inputType +"' value='" + val + "'/></td><td width='27%' align='left'>" + val + "</td>";

Answer (score 2):

Using the ItemDataBound event I would retrieve the radio button and compare it's value to your Session variable

something like this:

```
protected void MyDataList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton myRadioButton = e.Items.FindControl("myRadioButton") as RadioButton;

    if (myRadioButton == null) { }
    else
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session[myRadioButton.Value])) {}
        else myRadioButton.Checked = true;        
    }
}
```

Comment: After reading your comment you might want to add in the proper control server-side. It would be a lot cleaner. In my example you could just use a switch statement on your inputType type and create and add the proper control to the Item.